# I accidentally deleted a picture in my album on FB and it was uploaded years ago and I dont have a copy how can i get it back

Tags: photo, photo-gallery

I am not tech savvy but I was taking a picture that I have had on my FB act album since 2007 and trying to copy it. It was of the first moments after my daughter was born and they laid her in my arms after a Cesarian section.  It is the only place I had the picture. No other copys. The actual camera was lost. I was trying to do a "then and now picture" her birth to her first day of kindergarten and now I have lost it by accidentally hitting delete instead of copying.

Is there ANYWAY to get it back? Does FB have a trash folder?

Beth

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Facebook.

Comment: Try contacting support.

Answer (score 3):

So, I know this question is probably off-topic but I can't help but feel bad for lost baby photos.

First of all, if anyone else tagged the photo, it would be linked to their account as well. If you've ever emailed anyone the photo, likely you would have either sent the photo itself or a direct link to the facebook website where it's stored. It's probably still stored there, but now you just have (unfortunately) no way to access it. So if you ever sent the link to anyone, if you find the link, it will still link to the page.

If you're someone who doesn't routinely purge your browsing history, there may be a chance that a copy of the photo was saved to your browser's temporary files folder while you were looking at the photo. If you use Internet Explorer 7 or 8, here's a guide. Otherwise just Google "`<your browser name and version>` temp folder location".

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/view-temporary-internet-files

Of course, neither of these may work. If so, sorry for your loss of data. Good luck!